# Rotate the root of a BVH animation around Y axis by an angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

**Even if you are not familiar with BVH file format, maybe you could help me on how to combine two rotations.**

I just take the root's rotation (copying x,y,z values) from BVH file that the channels of the root as set like this:

`CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation`

And I want to rotate the root by some degrees could be 0 up to 360, around y axis (0,1,0). This rotation works at some frames. However, at most of the frames, the root is rotated strangely (it is like a gimbal lock has happened).

This is the code I use. C# in Unity. I just want to apply the root's rotation around y axis correctly.

**I can confirm that the code works fine (correct BVH animation) when adding 0 degrees rotation around y axis. So, the error has to be in the combination of those 2 rotations (qBefore and YawRotationQuaternion).**

```
private Vector3 getFinalRootRotation(Vector3 rotationFromBvh, float angle)
{
    // [INITIALIZE]: Convert Euler to Quaternion for each axis. 
    Quaternion qX = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationFromBvh.x, Vector3.right);
    Quaternion qY = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationFromBvh.y, Vector3.up);
    Quaternion qZ = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationFromBvh.z, Vector3.forward);
    Quaternion qBefore = qY * qX * qZ; // Multiply them in the correct order.
                                       // Order in BVH file is ZXY.
```

`qY*qX*qZ` has exaclty the **same euler x,y,z results** as `Quaternion.Euler(rotationFromBvh)`

```
    // [CREATE ROTATION AROUND Y]: Get the quaternion of rotating around y axis.
    Quaternion YawRotationQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.up);

    // [APPLY ROTATION AROUND Y]
    Quaternion qAfter = qBefore * YawRotationQuaternion;

    // [RETURN IN XYZ FORM]
    return qAfter.eulerAngles;
}
```

My goal is to create a new BVH that has the new root's rotation. This is the part of the code where I write the new rotation in the file. This code is tested and creates a BVH file ok.

```
private string CreateMLine(Vector3 rootPosition, Vector3 rootRotation, List<Vector3> rotations)
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    // Apply root's translation and rotation.
    s.Append(rootPosition.x + " " + rootPosition.y + " " + rootPosition.z + " ");
    s.Append(rootRotation.z + " " + rootRotation.x + " " + rootRotation.y + " ");

    for(int i=1; i<rotations.Count; i++) // start at 1 ==> skip rotation of the root.

    {
        s.Append(rotations[i].z + " " + rotations[i].x + " " + rotations[i].y + " ");
    }
    s.Append("\n");
    return s.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'ld say you get the values of the BVH in the order `Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation` for a good reason.

From [Quaternion.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html):

> A rotation that rotates euler.z degrees around the z axis, euler.x degrees around the x axis, and euler.y degrees around the y axis **(in that order)**.

So I think the mistake lies in

```
Quaternion qBefore = qY * qX * qZ;
```

which uses an incorrect order.

---

it should rather be

```
Quaternion qBefore = qZ * qX * qY;
```

---

I'ld suggest to use [Quaternion.Euler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) instead

> Returns a rotation that rotates z degrees around the z axis, x degrees around the x axis, and y degrees around the y axis.

```
Quaternion qBefore = Quaternion.Euler(rotationFromBvh.x, rotationFromBvh.y, rotationFromBvh.z);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried 3 ways of creating the Quaternion.

`1. qYXZ = qY * qX * qZ
2. qZXY = qZ * qX * qY
3. qEul = Quaternion.Euler(rotationFromBvh)`

The result is that (1) qYXZ and (3) qEul have the same euler angle values. Also, by viewing the BVH animation I can tell that (2) qZXY does not give the correct rotation.

(sorry about editing 3 times. I kept pressing enter. First time replying on stackoverflow)

Comment: did you try it also for those frames where your solution results in a gimble-lock?

Comment: Yes. qZXY does not give correct results. I'd like to metion that the code works fine (correct BVH animation) when adding 0 degrees rotation around y axis. So, the error has to be when combining `qBefore` and `YawRotationQuaternion`.

Answer (score 0):

Physically, quaternion multiplication means applying rotation from right to left.

q1 * q2 means rotate by q2 and then q1

So if you want to apply a rotation after another, put it on the left hand side.

In you case, it should be:

```
Quaternion qAfter = YawRotationQuaternion * qBefore;
```